# scroll left side of div only using page scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Today I had a look on the [foursquare.com](http://foursquare.com) website, when I search something in my city, it return me to the result page, and in the result page, when I scroll the page down using the page scroll bar, only the left column containing the listview of places detail scrolled down, not the right hand side of the page, I just want to know how that can be done using jquery or javascript. 
suppose I have the following html div:

```
     <html><body>
       <div id="wrapper" style="width:900px;height:1200px;margin: 0 auto;">

        <div id="left_column" style="width:300px;height:1200px; float:left;border:1px solid #000000;">
         <ul><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li><li>list 1</li></ul>
            </div>

      <div id="middle_column" style="width:300px;height:1200px; float:left;border:1px solid #000000;"></div>

        <div id="right_colunm" style="width:300px;height:1200px; float:left;border:1px solid #000000;"></div>
      </div>

      </body></html>
```

when I using the page scroll bar, only the content in the left_column is scrolled, not the middle one and the right one, can any one show me how to do it in jquery. any help will be grately appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, without jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style type="text/css">
#left {
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  width: 149px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
#right {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="left"> 
  <ul>
    <li>Start</li>

    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>

    <li>End</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="right"> 
  <div style="float:left">
    <p>Content start</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>  
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content end</p>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left:10px;float:left">
    <p>right start</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right</p>
    <p>right end</p>
  </div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually just CSS. The map in the background and header are set to `position: fixed` so that they stay in one place while the rest of the page scrolls.